# Run a command from a shell in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run a command in the shell from python and add some "----" for each line, but what the command returns is lines but in a block and python doesn't add "--" until the last line

What I expect it to return:

```
/usr/sbin/mount.nfs
-----
/usr/sbin/mount.cifs
-----
/usr/sbin/pppd
----
```

What returns me (using code A ):

```
/usr/sbin/mount.nfs
/usr/sbin/mount.cifs
/usr/sbin/pppd
----
```

The code A:

```
separador = "----------------"
shell = ['find', '/', "-perm", "-u=s", "-type", 'f']
output = subprocess.run((shell),capture_output= True, universal_newlines=True, text=True)   
command_output=(output.stdout+"\n"+separador)
print(command_output)
```

What returns me (using code B):

```
----------------
e
----------------
l
----------------
p
----------------
e
----------------
r
----------------
```

The code B:

```
separador = "----------------"
shell = ['find', '/', "-perm", "-u=s", "-type", 'f']
output = subprocess.run((shell),capture_output= True, universal_newlines=True, text=True)   
command_output=(output.stdout)

for i in command_output:
    print(i)
    print(separador)
```

Comment: `output.stdout` is the **entire** output from the command.  You're adding `separador` on to the end of that, _one time_.  Why would you expect `separador` to be added after _each line_?

Answer (score 2):

`command_output` is type `str`. after you collect it. split it line by line and insert your separator.

```
import subprocess

separador = "----------------"
shell = ['find', '/', "-perm", "-u=s", "-type", 'f']
output = subprocess.run(
    shell,
    capture_output=True,
    universal_newlines=True,
    text=True
    )

command_output = output.stdout
for i in command_output.splitlines():
    print(i)
    print(separador)
```

Comment: Note: you could replace your (imperative) for loop with sth like: `print("\n----------------\n".join(command_output.splitlines()))`

Comment: no thanks. I like one-lines, but that one doesn't do it for me.